# Compiled typescript node app throwing "Driectory import '...' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from '...'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, tsconfig, nx-monorepo

I'm building a full-stack web application in a monorepo managed by NX, the back-end server is a NodeJS/Express monolith written in typescript (this app was created using `nx g @nx/node:application app`).

The structure of the monorepo is as follows

```
root/
  apps/
    api/
      config/
        config.ts // This builds a config object from env vars, etc...
        index.ts // index file exporting config object
      src/
        routes/..
        resources/..
        app.ts
        init.ts
        main.ts // entry point
      tsconfig.app.json // extends ./tsconfig.json
      tsconfig.json // extends ../../tsconfig.base.json
  project.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.base.json
```

For local development I'm using the generated `nx serve app` command, compilation is successful however when node tries to run the compiled Javascript I'm greeted with this error:

```
Error: Directory import 'dist/apps/api/apps/api/config' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from dist/apps/api/apps/api/src/main.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:227:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:315:34)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1164:37)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:431:21)
```

I've not seen this error in past typescript apps I've written. So I created a reference app, in the same monorepo, generated with `nx g @nx/node:application reference` to see if the same error would appear. I structured it like this:

```
root/
  apps/
   reference/
     foo/
       foo.ts
       index.ts
     src/
       main.ts
     // the default generated tsconfig's from nx
```

Code:

`reference/foo/foo.ts`

```js
export const foo = () => console.log('Foo');
```

`reference/foo/index.ts`

```js
export * from './foo';
```

`reference/src/main.ts`

```
import * as Foo from '../foo';
Foo.foo();
```

I've also tried refactoring the import to target the file directly: `import { config } from '../config';` -> `import { config } from '../config/config';`. But I end up with this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dist/apps/api/apps/api/config/config' imported from dist/apps/api/apps/api/src/main.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:315:34)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1164:37)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:431:21)
```

The reference app built and ran without error. So my guess is that something is wrong with my TypeScript configuration in my api app. I can't find anything online short of implementing babel to transpile my compiled JS - I shouldn't have to do this as reference works fine. I've included the config for api below.

`tsconfig.base.json`

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

`apps/api/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

`apps/api/tsconfig.app.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "config/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

It's worth mentioning that `main.ts` imports `config` asynchronously in an initialization function: `const { config } = await import('../config');`. In the compiled javascript tsc keeps it as:

```js
  const { config } = await import("../config");
```

Whereas for the reference app, the import is converted to:

```js
var foo = __toESM(require("../foo"));
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!